# First time trying to install, keyboard and mouse not working

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 18.10

Im trying to install ubuntu for the first time to try it out. Ive made the usb boot drive and am booting into it fine.

If I boot into ubuntu to try it out, or try to install it, neither the keyboard or mouse work.

Im using an MSI gaming laptop.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: What do you mean "neither the keyboard or mouse work"? Do you get a light on a keyboard if you press Capslock? Can you press and hold left Shift before booting and then start in recovery mode and check if you can type in terminal there? Are you able to press Ctrl+Alt+2 to switch to terminal?

Comment: Hi. I got it working. I think adding acpi=off and nouveau.modeset=0 and maybe something else. That was only the start of my problems with Ubuntu. After that overall performance was bad, took AGES to set up and configure things, the fn key wouldnt work, there were only really silly ways to adjust the brightness and volume, the system wouldnt shutdown or reboot without being forced etc etc...

Comment: I got all my problems fixed in the end but the performance of ubuntu was overall what made me quit using it. After that I tried manjaro and it was a literal world away from ubuntu. Everything just worked right away. However due to an error in grub on booting I eventually gave up on it too and just went back to windows. Im still in total dismay as to how Ubuntu is supposed to be the most popular and user friendly version of Linux. It absolutely is not out of all the distros I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem mentioned here - when i installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS on MSI Gaming Laptop GL63. I had to turn off acpi=off to get my mouse & keyboard working.

For those who face the same problem in future :

follow the steps to to turn off acpi etc.

https://medium.com/@gentra/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-msi-ge62-6qc-ae4f30f50465